# Install after download within a script?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, batch-file, windows-installer

I would like to download an msi and install it, all silently within a script.  I wanted to try something like `start iexplore.exe http://domain.com/file.msi /qn`but unfortunetaley, it will just download the MSI and not begin the install.
Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  I haven't tested it, but I at least had the JScript functions already made from another project.  Save this with a `.bat` extension, modify the `set url=` line as appropriate, and run it.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

set url=http://domain.com/file.msi
set saveloc=%temp%\file.msi

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%url%" "%saveloc%"

msiexec /i "%saveloc%" /qn /norestart

:installwait
ping -n 2 0.0.0.0 >NUL
wmic process where name="msiexec.exe" get name 2>NUL | find /i "msiexec" >NUL && goto installwait

del "%saveloc%"

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */

function fetch(url) {
    var xObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xObj.open("GET",url,true);
    xObj.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    xObj.send('');
    while (xObj.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);
    return(xObj);
}

function save(xObj, file) {
    var stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    with (stream) {
        type = 1;
        open();
        write(xObj.responseBody);
        saveToFile(file, 2);
        close();
    }
}

save(fetch(WSH.Arguments(0)), WSH.Arguments(1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the script.  It comes back with this response: 'H:\My Documents\Kbox.bat(39, 9) ADODB.Stream: Arguments are of the wrong type, a
re out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.'

Comment: @RaptorPete - I don't think I can troubleshoot unless you tell me the URL of the MSI file you're trying to download.

Answer (score 0):

You must also 'start' the downloaded file. It will download to the default download location (C:\Users[username]\Downloads in Windows 7, unless it has been changed). However, you must have the file wait until the download completes, or else it won't be able to run the msi. As far as I know, there's not a way built in to have it check for you, so you just have to account for the longest expected download time, in seconds. The waiting can be done a few different ways, depending on which OS you're using. One example is

```
timeout /t [seconds] /nobreak > NUL
```

This accepts a wait time in seconds, and the /nobreak means that it ignores keypresses (which would normally indicate to proceed before the timer is done.). Another method is to have the batch file ping an invalid IP address (1.1.1.1) for a certain number of milliseconds. For example

```
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w [milliseconds] >NUL
```

Hope this helps.